# Windows boot to Mac harddrive

Tags: windows, macos, hard-drive, boot-camp

I have an mac hard drive which i salvaged from my old mac that broke down. Currently i have it installed on a new Windows computer (The drive is recognized and with the help of other programs, access files on it). How would I boot osx up on the old hard drive? I have tried to boot it up from the hard drive in BIOS but it boots to the Boot Camp partition I installed on it (and it blue screens half way through boot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't unless you use that hard drive with a Mac (even then a reinstall would be necessary). Apple uses security measures to ensure OS X can't be used on non-Apple hardware.

Comment: I have an mac that i can use. Can i somehow fix it?

Comment: depends on what is the problem. you can ask on http://apple.stackexchange.com/ to get better help about apple products.

Comment: Btw do you know anything about the bootcamp partition bluescreening?

Comment: It could be due to several reasons but none you can solve on a non-Apple computer. Apple's abusement of industry standards tends to have side effects like this. :)

Comment: Thank you, ill go install a fresh copy of osx and copy the files over then.